# How can I remove data which is stored in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

If I console.log(localStorage.getItem("cartCache")), the result like this :

```
{"dataCache":[{"id":20,"quantity":1,"total":100000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:31:00"},{"id":53,"quantity":1,"total":200000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:38:00"}]}
```

I want to remove the data in the cache by id

For example, I remove id = 20, it will remove id = 20 in the cache

So the result to be like this :

```
{"dataCache":[{"id":53,"quantity":1,"total":200000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:38:00"}]}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: For localStorage, it is a string, not an object. So you will have to get the Item, edit it and update it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#splice()` to delete an element from an array. Use `JSON.parse()` to get the object from the `localStorage` and then iterate through your array and delete the elements by comparing their id and then store the result back to localStorage.

```
var str = localStorage.getItem('cartCache'); 
var cartCache = JSON.parse(str);
var idToRemove = 20;
cartCache.dataCache.forEach((obj,i) => {
  if(obj.id === idToRemove)
    cartCache.dataCache.splice(i,1);
});
localStorage.setItem('cartCache', JSON.stringify(cartCache));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the object modify it and then store it again in local storage,

```
var retrievedObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartCache"));
retrievedObj.dataCache[0].id = 53;
localStorage.setItem('cartCache', JSON.stringify(retrievedObj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/rhwf1j5g/1/

```js
var data = {"dataCache":[{"id":20,"quantity":1,"total":100000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:31:00"},{"id":53,"quantity":1,"total":200000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:38:00"}]};

var removeid = 20;

var newData = $.grep(data.dataCache, function(value) {
  return value.id != removeid;
});

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the solution for your scenario

```js
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartCache"));

var removeid = 20;

var newData = $.grep(data.dataCache, function(value) {
  return value.id != removeid;
});

localStorage.setItem("cartCache", { "dataCache" : newData });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const filtered = JSON.parse(localStorage.cartCache)
.dataCache.filter(filteredObj => filteredObj.id !== 20);

localStorage.cartCache = JSON.stringify({ "dataCache": filtered });
```

What I am simply doing here is using the `parse()` method of the `JSON` object to convert the item in `localStorage` to a JS object.
I'm chaining the call by accessing `dataCache` directly instead of assigning it to a variable, then I chain the `filter()` call as the return value of `dataCache` is an array. I'm filtering out data where `id` is not equal to `20`.
I assign the result to the `filtered` variable, afterwards I call `stringify()` passing in the `filtered` result.
Finally, I save it to `localStorage`.

```js
// LocalStorage Mock
let localStorageMock = (function() {
  var storage = {};

  return {
    setItem: function(key, value) {
      storage[key] = value || '';
    },
    getItem: function(key) {
      return storage[key] || null;
    },
    removeItem: function(key) {
      delete storage[key];
    },
    get length() {
      return Object.keys(storage).length;
    },
    key: function(i) {
      var keys = Object.keys(storage);
      return keys[i] || null;
    }
  };
})();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: localStorageMock });


// Code you need
localStorage.cartCache = JSON.stringify({"dataCache":[{"id":20,"quantity":1,"total":100000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:31:00"},{"id":53,"quantity":1,"total":200000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:38:00"}]});

const filtered = JSON.parse(localStorage.cartCache)
.dataCache.filter(filteredObj => filteredObj.id !== 20);

localStorage.cartCache = JSON.stringify({ "dataCache": filtered });
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.cartCache));
```