# How can I remove data by index array which is stored in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

If I console.log(localStorage.getItem("cartCache")), the result like this :

```
{"dataCache":[{"id":20,"quantity":1,"total":100000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:31:00"},{"id":53,"quantity":1,"total":200000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:38:00"}],"expired":"2017-08-28T03:55:21.521Z"}
```

I want to remove the data in the cache by index array

For example, When I remove index array = 0, the result to be like this :

```
{"dataCache":[{"id":53,"quantity":1,"total":200000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:38:00"}]}
```

Another example, When I remove index array = 1, the result to be like this :

```
{"dataCache":[{"id":20,"quantity":1,"total":100000,"request_date":"27-08-2017 20:31:00"}]}
```

How can I do it?

I try like this :

```
var deleteIndex = 1;
var retrievedObj = localStorage.getItem("cartCache")
delete retrievedObj['dataCache'][deleteIndex];
```

It seems that is not the right way

Comment: what you have tried so far? please add your code here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Dinesh, This is not duplicate. My array is different

Comment: apply the same concept on your array to remove. doesn't matter here whether your array is different or not.

Comment: Take values from localStorage, use `javascript` methods to remove from json array. For eg. `delete cache.dataCache[0];` where is cache is variable which has value from localStorage.

Comment: @Dinesh, I update my question

Comment: @Amogh, It seems that is not the right way

Comment: @SuccessMan what is happening with your current code? any errors? check console

Comment: @SuccessMan check this http://jsfiddle.net/yjcL5/103/. You have to understand what `delete` and `splice` does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove data which is stored in local storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903858/how-can-i-remove-data-which-is-stored-in-local-storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splice` to remove an item from the array

```
// Clearing all localStorage value. No need to use below line in your code
localStorage.clear();
// to be stored object
var x = {
  "dataCache": [{
    "id": 20,
    "quantity": 1,
    "total": 100000,
    "request_date": "27-08-2017 20:31:00"
  }, {
    "id": 53,
    "quantity": 1,
    "total": 200000,
    "request_date": "27-08-2017 20:38:00"
  }],
  "expired": "2017-08-28T03:55:21.521Z"
}
// Initially storing it in local storage using JSON.stringify
localStorage.setItem('storeData', JSON.stringify(x));
// Once stored retrieving the value using JSON.parse
var getItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeData'));
// setting the dataCache with new array. The new array will be created as splice is used. splice is used to remove an item from array,
//0 is the index of the array, while second parameter 1 is to represent how many item to be removed starting from 0 ndex
getItem.dataCache = getItem.dataCache.splice(0, 1);
console.log(getItem); // the modified object
// after operation setting it to local storage
localStorage.setItem('storeData', JSON.stringify(getItem))
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/yyke2unf/)

Answer (score 4):

`localStorage.getItem("cartCache")` returns you two objects - *dataCache* and *expired*. If you want to remove the element `n` of *dataCache*, remove it by

```
localStorage.getItem("cartCache").dataCache.splice(n,1);
```

To fit it in your code:

```
var deleteIndex = 1;
var retrievedObj = localStorage.getItem("cartCache");
retrievedObj.dataCache.splice(deleteIndex,1);
```

Then `console.log` your localStorage again and you'll see the element removed.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword "delete" deletes deleteIndex only in retrieveObj it doesn't update your localStorage value. In order to update localStorage use:

```
var deleteIndex = 1;
var retrievedObj = localStorage.getItem("cartCache")
delete retrievedObj['dataCache'][deleteIndex];
localStorage.setItem("cartCache", retrieveObj)
```